# Adjusting pool size of akka.net cluster pool router

Tags: cluster-computing, akka.net

Here's the scenario I am looking to achieve using Akka.Net clustering:

- A user submits a load generation task to be performed, to a coordinator actor. (The task has its parameters and a 'load factor' - so a factor of 10 would create 10 parallel tasks.)
- The coordinator actor creates a cluster pool router with pool size equal to the load factor, and broadcasts a message to tell the routees to execute the task.
- As expected, the required number of routees is created on the cluster nodes, and the load is generated.

Now, I need to enable a ramp-up and ramp-down capability. I am looking to do that by periodically adjusting the pool size so every x seconds, the pool size is increased for a ramp-up, and for ramp-down, every x seconds, the pool size is reduced.

The cluster pool router is created using the following to create an initial pool of 1 routee:

```
ClusterRouterPoolSettings settings = new ClusterRouterPoolSettings(1, 1000, false, "worker");
var props = Props.Create<TestActor>(() => new TestActor())
              .WithRouter(new ClusterRouterPool(new BroadcastPool(100), settings));
var testActorRouter = Context.ActorOf(props, actorName);
```

To ramp up pool size by 5, the coordinator uses the following:

```
testActorRouter.Ask<Router>(new AdjustPoolSize(5));
```

However, this results in the 5 routees being added on the *coordinator's node*, instead of on the other cluster nodes. This is in spite of the pool settings specifying the role as "worker" (which the coordinator node doesn't have) and specifying local routees = false.

Is there a different way to adjust the pool size so it increases the cluster pool routees?

Thanks!